# Logout function works on one server not on another?

Tags: php

I have a very basic PHP logout file which will destroy the session on the user and will log them out of their account. This PHP file works on a server with PHP 5.2.17 (000webhosting).

But it doesn't work on a server with PHP 5.3.21, it basically doesn't logout the user.

This is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

session_destroy(); 
$_SESSION = array();
if(!session_is_registered('id')){ 
$msg = "You are now logged out";
} else {
$msg = "<h2>could not log you out</h2>";
} 
?> 
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "$msg"; ?><br>
<p><a href="login.php">Click here</a> to return to our home page </p>
</body>
</html>
```

does anyone know whats causing this issue?

I also used this on the new server and still didn't work:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['id']);
session_destroy(); 
$_SESSION = array();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ 
$msg = "You are now logged out";
} else {
$msg = "<h2>could not log you out</h2>";
} 
?> 
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "$msg"; ?><br>
<p><a href="login.php">Click here</a> to return to our home page </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[ 0 ] = "id";
session_destroy(); 
unset($_SESSION['0']);
if(!isset($_SESSION['0'])){ 
$msg = "By Clicking The Button Below, You Will Agree That You will Be Logged Out.";
} else {
$msg = "<h2>could not log you out</h2>";
} 
?>
```

it is very strange that I have to refresh the members page once from the browser so it will show the users as logged out. if I don't do the page refresh, it will stay logged in!!!

Comment: I just did. sorry about that. it means it doesn't logout the user out of their account. its a logout page.. it doesn't do 1000s of other things... it only logs the users out of their account. it doesn't work means it doen't do what it should do.

Comment: Probably using an [Deprecated & Removed session_is_registered()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php) function on a server that now has PHP 5.4

Comment: are you on PHP 5.4? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php

Comment: What version you used before and what version you use now...version 0.2 instead of 0.1 or what. newer version and older version can be everything!

Comment: the PHP version is 5.3.21 on the new server.

Comment: And the exact version of the old server?

Comment: May be unrelated, but just remove $_SESSION = array(); line. It's not necessary.

Comment: @halfer, the old server is 000web hosting which is PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: @roozi - that should go in your question, have edited for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**session_is_registered()** is *deprecated*, so instead try using this:

→ On the page where you call **session_register()**

```
     session_start();
     $_SESSION[ 0 ] = "id"; // in place of session_register()
```

→ And on the page where you use **session_is_registered()**

→ **EDIT:** Includes refresh tag as "*macgyver fix*" for session bug

```
     session_start();
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">'; // auto-refresh

     if( !isset( $_SESSION[ 0 ] ) ) // in place of session_is_registered()
     { 
          echo "You are now logged out"; 
     }
     else 
     {
          echo "<h2>could not log you out</h2>";
     }
```

Comment: well, I have tried the !isset on the new server as I was getting deprecated error and you can view my code above. but that didn't work either!! I also used your  $_SESSION[ 'id' ] = "id"; suggestion and still no luck :(

Comment: @rooziFar What output do you get if you put echo $_SESSION[ 'id' ] right below session_start(); ?

Comment: what output do i have to try to see? I did place <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?> right at the top of my code to see if there is any error and there is NO error at all.

Comment: @rooziFar Try my updated answer, I found some info that makes me think associative arrays stay after session destruction for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That solution worked in a way. BUT, It doesn't work all the time!! If i logout and visit the users account again, it will show me as already logged in and if I logout again and refresh the "logout page" a few times and then refresh the "users page2 a few times and then visit the users page, then the logout function works!! this is very strange. I have never seen anything like this!!

Comment: I also followed your solution and changed the unset($_SESSION['id']); to unset($_SESSION['0']);  and now I only have to refresh the page once for the logout function to work!! narrowing it down so to speak.

Comment: @rooziFar Hmm, whenever you want to destroy the $_SESSION, use the new code at the end of my updated answer and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: doesn't your code need session start at the top? also, that looks very familiar! I think I have used that code from PHP website and it didn't work. lets try it again.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work. I have updated my post so you can see my new code. it works But I have to refresh the member's page once and it will show me as logged out. very strange..

Comment: @rooziFar Hmmm.. well try my updated answer and see if adding a meta tag telling the browser to auto-refresh works

Comment: I thought about doing that to be honest. I will update this post as soon as I've tried that.

Comment: @rooziFar The meta refresh isn't the most elegant fix, but as long as it works that's 10x better than the code not working lol